# function(this.id) not working on click of angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a html button that has an id, and I want to send the id of the button, but not as writing the id on the field, I want to send it as `this.id` but I cannot perform this.

```
<button (click)="changeEnergy(this.id)" id="flash" [ngClass]="!theme?'btnEnergy1':'btnEnergy2'">
        <i id="flashIcon" class="fa-solid fa-bolt iconFlash"></i>
</button>
```

I tried by writing the id manually and it worked, but I want to send it like that as `this.id` because the id of the element changes, it is not the same id, so I need to send the `this.id` but I am not able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the angular way by using a template variable referring to this button.

```
<button (click)="changeEnergy(flash.id)" id="flash" 
    [ngClass]="!theme?'btnEnergy1':'btnEnergy2'" #flash>
            <i id="flashIcon" class="fa-solid fa-bolt iconFlash"></i>
</button>
```

Here, Note the `#flash` which references the button element which we can use instead of this in pure js

Answer (score 1):

welcome to stack overflow first of all!
Regarding your question, the `id` you are trying to pass to `changeEnergy` is the value of `id` method of yuour class.
In order to access to the id of your element you have to write

```html
<button (click)="changeEnergy($event)" id="flash" [ngClass]="!theme?'btnEnergy1':'btnEnergy2'">
        <i id="flashIcon" class="fa-solid fa-bolt iconFlash"></i>
</button>
```

And for retrieving the `id` in your template:

```
  public changeEnergy(clickEvent: MouseEvent) {
    const id = (event.target as HTMElement).id;
  }
```

In this way your are retrieving which element is click and you are accessing to the `id`

Comment: thanks this might help for future implementation :D